# Hadoop Installation - Directory structure - /etc/hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I downloaded hadoop 2.7 and each installation guide that I have found mentions `/etc/hadoop/..` directory but the distribution that I have downloaded doesn't have this directory.

I tried with Hadoop 2.6 as well and it doesn't have this directory either.

Should I create these directories ?

Caveat; I am a complete newbie !
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mention the installation guide you are following. Generally /etc/ directory stores configuration files only. In hadoop installation this contain either the configuration files or symlinks to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have downloaded the source. Build the Hadoop source then you will get that folder.

To build the hadoop source, refer building.txt file available in the Hadoop package that you have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading `hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz` instead of `hadoop-2.6.0-src.tar.gz` from [Hadoop Archive](https://www.apache.org/dist/hadoop/core/hadoop-2.6.0/). As @Kumar has mentioned, you might have source distribution.

If you don't want to compile hadoop from source, then download `hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz` from the link given above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download compiled hadoop from the below link
http://a.mbbsindia.com/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.6.0/hadoop-2.6.0.tar.gz instead of downloading source

you will get the /etc/hadoop/.. path in it..

Answer (score 0):

Download it from Apache Website

[Apache Hadoop link](http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html)